# Use get_object_or_404 to get only one field rather than all fields specified in model in django rest framework?

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to get just one field as a result from get_object_or_404 but it is not seem to be working for me.

I am using the User model from the default auth app of django.
This is my serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=254)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
```

This is my view:

```
class UserView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, id=None):

        if id:
               data = 
               get_object_or_404(User.objects.only('username'), 
               id=id)
            serializer = UserSerializer(data, many=False)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
                data = get_list_or_404(User)
            serializer = UserSerializer(data, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Even after using this `get_object_or_404(User.objects.only('username'), id=id)` I am still getting all the fields specified in the serializer rather than just the username.

This is the response i get when i pass an id to the api while calling it from the postman.

```
{
    "username": "admin",
    "email": "admin@email.com",
    "first_name": ""
}
```

rather than this:

```
{
    "username": "admin",
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the doc of  [**`get_object_or_404`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)

> Calls **`get()`** on a given model manager, but it raises **`Http404`** instead of the model’s **`DoesNotExist`** exception.

You don't need to expect it would return only a single value.

---

#### Solution

remove other fields than the **`username`** from your serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
```

---

The more generic solution would be, Use ***two different serializers for both purposes***

```
# serializers.py
class UserListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=254)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)


class UserGetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)


# views.py
class UserView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, id=None):
        if id:
            user_instance = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
            serializer = UserGetSerializer(user_instance)  # used `UserGetSerializer`
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            user_qs = get_list_or_404(User)
            serializer = UserListSerializer(user_qs, many=True)  # used `UserListSerializer`
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here I created two serializer classes, **`UserListSerializer`** and **`UserGetSerializer`** and used them in view.

Comment: Thank you mate i appreciate your help. Though it seems like a nice hack still i am looking for something where i don't have to make multiple serializers.

Comment: According to the [**SOLID**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles, ***"A class should only have a single responsibility, that is, only changes to one part of the software's specification should be able to affect the specification of the class."***